# Sharing session data between two applications (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, digital-signature

There is an existing application that a user logs into. At a certain point within the existing user workflow the new application I am working on takes over for the existing application and some data from the current session needs to be shared. I was given an idea of digitally signing the data to ensure it is secure, but I am having trouble figuring out how I would implement this and how to share the session. The application I am working on is a rails app.

My question really contains two parts, if you have an idea for one and not the other, that's great:

1) Do you have an idea on how I would share the session between both applications?

2) Would you have an idea on how I would use public/private keys to encrypt the data I am sending?

Comment: You can use SAML to send session related data from one app to the other one and vice-versa, plus you can encrypt it for additional security with a private key which will be present in both your applications, but I am not sure of sharing a session. May be what you can do is create a Single Sign on feature. Once the user logs into one app and clicks a link to move to other app, you can use SAML to authenticate the user in other app without asking him to sign in again.

Comment: your question is very broad. could you give specific examples for what data you want to share and how the handover of sessions is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use RubyCAS for manage sessions between applications. It's easy to use and you can integrate it with Devise.

https://github.com/rubycas/rubycas-client

https://github.com/nbudin/devise_cas_authenticatable